# WebBrowser control: How to overwrite URL property

Tags: c#, .net, printing, webbrowser-control

This is a bit special:
I'm loading some HTML in string form into the WebBrowser control via the DocumentText property.
Now when I print the page with a PDF printer (Bullzip PDF Printer in my case) it always takes the URL as document name which is "about:blank".
Is there any way to change this to another value by either changing the URL property (it's read-only) or by changing the print behaviour to use another text rather than the URL as filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options that I am aware of though my knowledge on this subject is a bit dated.

The first is to change the computer settings in Internet Options.  Regardless of whether this is done by hand or through a registry change script, it is simple for the developer, but obviously not the best approach from the deployment or compatibility angles.

The next approach is to develop a custom print template.  This is not fun, but is probably the most professional approach.  As much as I would love to include all of the information needed on this approach in this post, it is too much to cover.  [Here is a good overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753280(VS.85).aspx) and good luck Googling from there.

My experience with this involved printing from the MS WebControl component used in a .NET 1.1 Winforms application to the Web Super Goo PDF converter component.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the header and footer such that the URL property is not printed.

Comment: The issue isn't about printing the URL, it's that the URL is used as document name (example: stackoverflow.com.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Try to `Navigate` to a URL, then cancel that via `DWebBrowserEvents::BeforeNavigate`

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work: Using C# I navigated to a URL and then in the .._Navigating event I've cancelled the navigation but the URL property is still left "null" and so "about:blank" is still used.